# Czech: "Býval + minulý čas" VS. minulý čas

Tags: grammar, czech

What is the difference between czech construction "býval + m.č." and m.č.?
**Harry by si *přál* mít aspoň čtyři páry oči navíc.
Harry by si *býval přál* mít aspoň čtyři páry oči navíc.**

Comment: bytebuster's answer is wrong, it's the past conjunctive.

Comment: @Atamiri Depends on how you translate the term to English, but there is usually *no* conjunctive in Czech.

Answer (score 3):

It is the [**past tense of the conditional mood**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood#Slavic_languages) (kondicionál minulý, podmiňovací způsob minulý). A short official and authoritative description in Czech can be found at http://prirucka.ujc.cas.cz/?id=575#nadpis2

Note you should use genitive *očí*, not nominative *oči*.

> Harry by si přál mít aspoň čtyři páry očí navíc.

*Harry would like to have at least four extra pairs of eyes.*

> Harry by si býval přál mít aspoň čtyři páry očí navíc.

*Harry would have liked to have at least four extra pairs of eyes.*

See also: James D. Naughton (2006) Czech: An Essential Grammar:

> To talk about what might have been in the past (but wasn't), you can
>   add **byl** or **býval** to the *conditional*, making a 'past
>   conditional', corresponding to 'would have done' in English. ...example... For
>   the past conditional of the verb **být** 'to be' use **byl býval**.

It is not that archaic as some claim. See http://nase-rec.ujc.cas.cz/archiv.php?art=6175 (in Czech). I cite and translate: *"We can therefore conclude that the thing is not that the past conditional would be disappearing from Czech; but it is **used only when the past is not signified by other means or if the past is not understood from context**.*

---

The question *explicitly asks* for the difference with m.č. (minulý čas), so:

The past tense (minulý čas, složené préteritum (compound preterite), developed from the Old Czech perfect tense) is the only non-archaic past tense in Czech:

> Harry chtěl mít aspoň čtyři páry očí navíc.

Harry wanted at least four extra pairs of eyes.

Comment: Could anyone comment what is wrong about my answer? I am a native Czech speaker (Common Czech dialect + standard Czech) and I do consider myself quite versed in this matter. I am not that stupid to assume that whoever comments was downvoting. I would like to know what is deemed wrong.

Comment: If it is just the form of the English past conditional, yes it is possible I translated it to English wrong. I had always problems with English conditional sentences. But **it definitely IS** the past conditional in Czech.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the claim that the past conjunctive is not archaic. Moreover the pluperfect is not part of the grammar since Old Czech, someone jokingly using it isn't proof it's still alive. Overall the answer doesn't address the question and isn't in agreement with modern Czech grammars.

Comment: What? Old Czech was in the 15th century and before. Past perfect was common still in the 19th century which is modern Czech (not speaking about middle (humanistic) Czech). Past conditional with "bejval bych" is common in vernacular Czech and any native speaker should agree with that. And I DID INCLUDE REFERENCES. See http://nase-rec.ujc.cas.cz/archiv.php?art=6175 Yes, present conditional is used more, but it has always been true. Even in middle Czech times.

Comment: You might be a native speaker but you are no linguist. The downvotes indicate you are off track.

Comment: @Atamiri BTW, to let you know how much you were just bullying, Naughton's Czech essential grammar does also mention pluperfect as an "occasional" tense in Czech. which is now "semi-obsolete". Please admit you were completely wrong with your "old Czech", because that is the time of aorists and imperfects and is long gone. I never claimed it wasn't archaic. But pluperfect is no longer part of my answer, it was a reaction to other, now deleted, post and I don't think my answer deserves to bu downvoted that much. All claims in my answer are backed by references from real linguists.

Comment: Czech speaker here and a linguist - this is a perfectly cromulent answer

Comment: @Atamiri With regard to your comment right under the question "*it's the past **conjunctive***", I tend not to trust your linguistic expertise. I am not aware of *any* Slavic language having *ever* had anything like the subjunctive. And I am pretty sure that Czech has never - never ever in its history (since the language is called Czech) - had the subjunctive. We in Slavic languages express the subjunctive constructions mostly by using conditional or omitting it at all. For native Slavic speakers the subjunctive is something absolutely artificial when they learn a foreign language.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Macedonian and Bulgarian have an elaborate system of subjunctives.

Comment: @Atamiri: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_language However, most contemporary Bulgarian linguists usually exclude the subjunctive mood and the inferential mood from the list of Bulgarian moods ... and don't consider them to be moods but view them as verbial morphosyntactic constructs or separate gramemes of the verb class.

Comment: @Atamiri: as for Makedonian, as far as I know they have rather "Potential mood" as the closest to subjunctive. But I agree that these two languages in general are are very different from the remaining Slavic languages. However, **Czech language does not have the subjunctive mood**, neither anything else like this. When we learn a foreign language, we have to **constantly focus** on using subjunctive where it belongs. It is like when the Finnish or Hungarians must focus on using properly the genders in English, as they do not think in genders at all. And they make funny sentences :)